# RXAndroid: get List objects from the difficult List

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have been trying for a long time to execute this code on Android, looking for answers here but not successfully. I'm a beginner developer, and please understand me.
I make multiple requests using Retrofit2 and RXJava

There is the answer, JSON (Array), it's class `CurrencyData` in Java

```
[
{ 
"r030":978,"txt":"euro","rate":11.11111,"cc":"EUR","exchangedate":"25.09.2018"
 }
]
```

MyAPI interface

```
@GET("/BankService/v1/statdirectory/exchange")
Observable<List<CurrencyData>> getCurrencyCodeDate(@Query("valcode") String valCode, @Query("date") String date);
```

collect requests

```
List<Observable<List<CurrencyData>>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
requests.add(myApi.getCurrencyCodeDate("USD","20180928"));
requests.add(myApi.getCurrencyCodeDate("EUR","20180928"));
```

execute requests

```
 Observable
           .zip(requests, Arrays::asList) 
           .toList()
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

I got

```
[[CurrencyData{txt='Dollar USA', rate='1.111'}], [CurrencyData{txt='EURO', rate='2.222'}]]
```

I'm interested in how to get a `List<CurrencyData>` with all the `CurrencyData` objects.

I tried to use `map` and `flatMap` - but it does not work.
I will be very grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks to me like you have what you say you want.

Comment: If I understood it right, You want `List<CurrencyData>` and not `List<List<CurrencyData>>` right?

Comment: @Kalpesh Patel
yes, but I get all the time not what I need

Comment: I guess you will have to use `collectInto` operator instead of `toList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:
Your `getCurrencyCodeDate` method returns `Observable` of `List<CurrencyData>`, And you are using it inside a `Observable.zip()` whith zipper func as `Arrays::asList`.

What is happening is, Your `getCurrencyCodeDate` emits a `List` of objects and `Arrays::asList` is wrapping all the emitted `List`s in a `List`. Resulting in `Observable.zip()` emitting `List<List<>>`.

On top of that `.toList()` operator is applied, which will again wrap emitted `List<List<>>` inside another `List` resulting in `List<List<List<>>>` as return type.

What you could do is, use `merge` operator instead of `zip` and use `collectInto` instead of `toList`.

```
Observable
            .merge(requests)
            .collectInto(new ArrayList<CurrencyData>(), ArrayList::addAll)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: It `s Magic. Everything works perfectly. I'm very grateful